# Redirecting to another page from 404 page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have custom 404 page that is configured with  `responseMode="ExecuteURL"`
I also have a master page where there is a search box.
When search box is submitted the page is redirected to `/Search.aspx?q=`
However if I am on the custom 404 page the redirection doesn't work.
I get something like this in the url

`http://localhost:49321/nothere?error=404&404%3bhttp%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a49321%2fnothere`

`http://localhost:49321/nothere` is the url where i tested my custom 404 page

it would work fine if response mode is set to `Redirect`, but i don't want that.

anyway to solve this?

here is rendered html for search box

```
<div id="searchPanel" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;searchButton&#39;)">

                    <input name="ctl00$searchBox" type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="     Search..." />
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$searchButton" value="" id="searchButton" style="display: none" />


</div>
```

Comment: How is your search box form implemented? Please show us the rendered HTML.

Comment: @Dai there is a button and onclick it calls a function in master.cs. i included rendered html for search box